# 8BitDo Bluetooth Controller

Tags: bluetooth, xinput, input-devices, gamepad, joystick

I'm having trouble making an 8BitDo Bluetooth controller work with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. The controller can successfully pair in all modes (Android, macOS and Windows) but it doesn't get recognized by RetroArch. It also doesn't work with browser-based games that support gamepads. Is it a permission problem? How can I make sure my user account has access to the device?

Update: I've found the device has been detected as `/dev/input/js0`. If I `cat` it, I can actually see some garbage being printed as I press the buttons, so it's not a permission issue related to my user account.

Update 2: after installing RetroArch via `apt`, it works, but I'd really rather use the previously `snap` installed one, as it has more features, e.g. downloading cores within the UI, etc.

Comment: Hello. In other then games such as mouse, keyboard or headset does the Bluetooth work?

Comment: Keyboard and mouse work fine, but they're not Bluetooth.

Comment: Not what I asked.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was installing the official AppImage version from https://retroarchofficial.itch.io/retroarch